# OpenGL ES 2 - glSwapBuffers?

Tags: opengl-es, ios, opengl-es2, ipad

this is what i do to blit FBO onto screen in ViewController:

```
[m_Context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

but i need something like **glSwapBuffers**, so that i can call it somewhere from the engine code ( which is cpp ) - to refresh the screen in special cases - is this available for iOS / how can i implement it - if i can at all..

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i have solved it by a small util function:

```
void SwapBuffers()
{
    EAGLContext* context = [EAGLContext currentContext];

    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];     
}
```